# Is counting on fetch to use the cache a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch, browser-cache

I'm fetching a static file. What are the downsides (if any significant ones) to fetching the same file multiple times instead of saving it in a local variable?

```
function getInfo(){
    fetch(src);
}

getInfo();
getInfo();
getInfo();
```

(Obviously I'm not running the same function 3 times in a row like this, but I do have a static file that's fetched often.)

1. Does `fetch` make any sort of call to the server even if the file's been loaded locally?
2. If so, is there a way to prevent that?
3. Is there a significant speed difference between using `fetch` and using a local variable for my large, static text files?

If I'm doubling up on space unnecessarily by saving static files from fetch into variables, I'd like to not do that. But if I'm just being lazy and it impacts server requests and speed significantly, I want to know that.

In Chrome, the console shows that the fetched file is cached and file will be grabbed from the cache if fetched again. I know other browsers may differ in how they handle `fetch` requests.

Anybody here deeply familiar with this? Does this vary a lot among browsers? Is there anything in the specs that would explain this?

Comment: why does your code attempt to fetch the same "static file" many times? rewrite your code so it only fetches it once :p

Comment: Like Jaromanda is saying, what's the reason for fetching the same static file multiple times?

I'd suggest you either save the data in some kind of state management, or save away the static file data in LocalStorage or SessionStorage

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm curious if with caching if it makes much of a difference though. I used to think it didn't but `fetch` caches files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Chrome, the console shows that the fetched file is cached and file will be grabbed from the cache if fetched again. I know other browsers may differ in how they handle fetch requests.

This shouldn't, in general, be browser-specific other than the browser expiring cached data if it runs out of cache space (different browsers may have different algorithms for choosing what to expire).

> Does `fetch` make any sort of call to the server even if the file's been loaded locally?

Whether the resource is re-requested or re-verified or satisifed entirely loally depends primarily on its cacheability, which depends on the caching headers you return with the resource from the server (`Expires`, `Cache-Control`, etc.). You can use those headers to say that the file should never be cached (by the browser, by proxies between the browser and server, etc.), or that it should be cached forever, or somewhere in-between.

If you ensure that the cache headers say the resource is cacheable for the period of time you want it cached, then you can expect the browser to respect that, provided it doesn't run out of cache space.

> If so, is there a way to prevent that?

Yes, set cache headers.

> Is there a significant speed difference between using fetch and using a local variable for my large, static text files?

Well, naturally the local variable is going to win dramatically in relative terms, near-zero time vs. at least a function call and check to see whether the item is cache and whether, if so, it needs to be re-validated or re-requested. But that's unlikely to be significant in absolute terms.

> If I'm doubling up on space unnecessarily by saving static files from fetch into variables, I'd like to not do that.

You will be in at least some sense, if the resource is cacheable, because the browser will cache it *and* you'll have a copy loaded as a string referenced by your local variable. But the browser's cached copy may be in persistent storage (loosely, "disk"), not in RAM, and it will get pushed out of RAM if necessary to make room for other cached items. Browsers typically use up to a fixed amount of RAM for their cache, so this item specifically probably won't increase the amount of RAM cache the browser uses.

---

Probably worth noting that you can use a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to insert your own code between the request and the browser cache.

Comment: `the browser will cache it and you'll have a copy loaded as a string referenced by your local variable` - of course, the fact that there's a cached copy isn't at all a "memory hit" as such, because browsers usually have x amount of RAM used for cache anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX - Thanks, I'll clarify, I didn't mean to imply two copies *in memory*.

Comment: well, you do have two in memory ... one in the RAM cache, and one in the program variable - but it's not like the RAM cache is something the browser isn't using anyway (as far as memory usage goes) ... sure, if you rely on the cache, your program memory usage could be less while you don't have a copy of that file in a variable

Answer (score 1):

When you load a file from the server, your browser sends a request to the server and loads its content into memory. This can take a lot of time.

If your browser caches the file, then, instead of sending a request to the server, the cached file is loaded into memory. This is also time consuming, but not as much as in the case of waiting for the response of the request.

You do not control the cache system of the browsers, so you will not know whether the file will be cached at all and if so, for how long will it be cached.

If you load the file into memory and reuse it, then it will be much quicker. Since we are talking about a file, you can make its contents to be wrapped into a function, so, instead of resending the request, you will just call the function if it is defined. The algorithm is to check whether a certain function exists. If so, call it, if not, load the file. If the file is cached, then it will be loaded from the cache. Otherwise, a request to the server will be sent.